# Complexity of fromValue() method in enumeration class

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have a class like this:

```
public enum ReturnCode{

Code1(
    "Code1",
    "Return this code when there is an erreur"
    ),

Code2(
    "Code2",
    "Return this code when everything ok"
    );

ReturnCode(final String code, final String detail) {
    this.code = code;
    this.detail = detail;
}

private static Map<String, ReturnCode> map =
        new HashMap<String, ReturnCode>();

static {
    for (ReturnCode returnCode : ReturnCode.values()) {
        map.put(returnCode.code, returnCode);
    }
}

public static ReturnCode fromValue(String code) {
    return map.get(code);
}
```

I just want to know in terms of complexity, is it better than :

```
public static returnCode fromValue(String code) {
        for (returnCode returnCode : returnCode.values()) {
            if (returnCode .code.equals(code)) {
                return returnCode ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Because it seems every time we call fromValue in the first method, it will generate a map so in all it's also O(n)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map is static object. Further it is populated by the code in the static code block. The static code block is called only once per class. No reason why map will be generated more than once.

This means that your second `fromValue()`, which is O(n), is going to be slower than the original `fromValue()` which is O(1) in terms of performance.